# Delete old package versions within a backup folder

Tags: files, arch-linux, pacman, version

I have a folder that contains a large number of `tar.xz` packages that have their version number in their filenames . ex :
`vlc-2.2.2-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz` (old and should be deleted)
`vlc-2.2.3-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz` (new so it should be kept)
the task of the bash script is to check for old packages and delete them , keeping new ones and packages that don't have duplicates.

Comment: lol yes kinda - the packages are from there yes , but they're in a new folder

Comment: @BlakeAngelo - try `pacman --cachedir=/path/to/pkgs -Sc`

Comment: @DarkHeart the packages aren't installed and

Comment: I'm not sure if this is directly applicable to your problem, but I'm on Debian and I use `apt-cacher-ng` as a proxy to take care of caching and it automatically purges old stuff based on whether it is still found in the `Packages` list I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right tool for this job is `paccache`<sup>1</sup>:

```
paccache -r -k 1 -c /path/to/cache/dir
```

This deletes `-r` all cached versions of each package except for the most recent one `-k 1` in the cache directory specified via `-c`
You can always move the old packages to another dir instead of deleting them immediately and only delete them later on.
Run `paccache -h` for more details.

---

<sup>1: A flexible pacman cache cleaning utility included in the pacman package</sup>

Comment: @BlakeAngelo - as you wish. It's easier to just boot from an arch/derivative livecd and do this than re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Done - and that worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Given a folder `pool`, keep the last 42 versions of each package.
This assumes the package name and its version are separated with an underscore.

```bsh
pkgs=`find ${pool} -type f | cut -f1 -d_ | sort | uniq`
for pkg in ${pkgs}; do
  find `dirname ${pkg}` -name "`basename ${pkg}`_*" | sort -rV | sed -e '1,42d' | xargs -r rm
done
```